# Passing argument to bash script in call for bsub function in python

Tags: python, bash

I would like to submit jobs from python with python function bsub in bsub module.

```py
bsub("test_job", 'test.sh', verbose=True)()
```

works for me.
But if I want to pass arguments to test.sh, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [bsub documentation](https://github.com/brentp/bsub#chaining)'s sample code snipets, just add arguments to the command string:

```py
bsub("test_job", 'test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3', verbose=True)()
```

Comment: @Haiying if it answers your question then don't forget to add the checkmark accepted answer.